# Add Auto Play To Existing Image Slider

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, slider

I am using an image slider for a website that I am building but it doesn't have an auto play feature. Can you add a custom auto play feature to it using jQuery? Source code below.

**Slider Preview**

[image]

**Aspx Page**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#slider1').cycle({
                fx: 'scrollHorz',
                speed: 'slow',
                timeout: 0,
                next: '#next',
                prev: '#prev',
                pager: '#thumb',
                pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
                    return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="60" height="60" /></a></li>';
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

    <section>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="slider">
                <div id="slider1">
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/B50.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/B51.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/C47.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/C43.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/E2.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/W5.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                    <img border="0" src="Slider/M21.JPG" width="850" height="637" />
                </div>
                <ul id="thumb"></ul>
                <div id='next' class="slider_next">
                    <img border="0" src="Images/next.png" width="57" height="57" alt="next image" /></div>
                <div id='prev' class="slider_prev">
                    <img border="0" src="Images/prev.png" width="57" height="57" alt="previous image" /></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Style**

```
.slider {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 850px;
    height: 637px;
    border: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333333;
    position: relative;
}

.slider_next {
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 287px;
    left: 820px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider_prev {
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 287px;
    left: -35px;
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#thumb {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 20px 14%;
}

    #thumb li {
        width: 60px;
        float: left;
        margin: 12px;
        list-style: none;
    }

    #thumb a {
        width: 60px;
        padding: 3px;
        display: block;
        border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333333;
    }

    #thumb li.activeSlide a {
        border: 3px solid #0a526f;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #333333;
    }

    #thumb a:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    #thumb img {
        border: none;
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: create a fiddle and share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this. This will change slide every 2 seconds

```
function changeSlide(){
    $('#next').trigger('click');
    setTimeout(changeSlide,2000);
}

setTimeout(changeSlide,2000);
```

so the final code will look like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slider1').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 0,
        next: '#next',
        prev: '#prev',
        pager: '#thumb',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (idx, slide) {
            return '<li><a href="#"><img src="' + slide.src + '" width="60" height="60" /></a></li>';
        }
    });

    function changeSlide(){
        $('#next').trigger('click');
        setTimeout(changeSlide,2000);
    }

    setTimeout(changeSlide,2000);

});
```

Comment: this is not gonna change on the next button click. The above code will simulate the next button click for every 2 seconds which gives the auto play effect